# Different signin and signout routes for multiple devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have 3 devise that are:

```
devise_for :hrs
devise_for :employes
devise_for :authorizes
```

I want to redirect to different pages after `sign_in` and same for `signout`

here is my code in `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

        protect_from_forgery with: :exception

def after_sign_in_path_for(authorizes)
       auth_main_path 
end
def after_sign_out_path_for(authorizes)
      new_authorize_session_path
 end
def after_sign_in_path_for(employes)
     employee_emain_path
 end
def after_sign_out_path_for(employes)
   new_employe_session_path
 end
 def after_sign_in_path_for(hrs)
    hrs_hhome_path
  end
 def after_sign_out_path_for(hrs)
    new_hr_session_path
 end
end
```

The `sign_in` works but the `problem` is in the `sign_out`

my `sign_out` button is:

```
 <%= link_to "SIGNOUT", destroy_authorize_session_path, :method => :delete ,:data => { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>
```

**I want only one `signout` button for current_Session**
May be anyone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for that make your own routes for sign out, then create a function, in which capture all three session of employes, hrs, authorizes and make it nil or destroy....

eg.

```
def signout_all
  if hrs_session
    hrs_session.destroy
  elsif employee_session
    employee_session.destroy
  else
    authorizes_session.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry but you did not get my  question, i want to sign_out only the session which have signed_in.mean if i have signed in as a employee the when i click on sign_out the employee session should be delete and redirect to specific page.

Comment: you write this so i give the solution according that "I want only one signout button for all users May be anyone can help me. Thanks"

Comment: yeah sorry my mistake..i agree.can you  help me now..?

Comment: in devise if you want user session then you use user_session it return user session same as in your app you check employee_session or hrs_session etc if any one exist then destroy that.

Comment: nothing special just create a routes which goes this action.... signout_all and write aboce code inside the action

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this problem.
But first, don't get me wrong, but I can't believe that after_sign_in works too. You're redefining after_sign_in_path_for(some_model) multiple times. From what I see, it should always use 'hrs_home_path'.

So, how can you solve it?
You need to define after_sign_in_path and after_sign_out_path like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  case resource_or_scope
    when :hr, Hr
      auth_main_path
    when :authorize, Authorize
      auth_main_path
    when :employee, Employee
      employee_main_path
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  case resource_or_scope
    when :hr, Hr
      new_hr_session_path
    when :authorize, Authorize
      new_authorize_session_path
    when :employee, Employee
      new_employee_session_path
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what should i edit on my sign_out button ?`<%= link_to "SIGNOUT", destroy_authorize_session_path, :method => :delete ,:data => { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>`

Comment: Leave it as it is. It should work with these changes.

Comment: Maybe there's some mistake in case statement. Do you know how to use pry debugger?